# NSIS round disk size to nearest decimal place

Tags: nsis

The following code returns the size of the system drive in GB:

```
!include logiclib.nsh
section
  system::call 'kernel32::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(t"$windir", *l.r0, *l, *l)'
  size:
    ${if} $0 u> 1024
      system::int64op $0 / 1024
      pop $0
      goto size
    ${endif}
  detailprint $0
sectionend
```

How do i get the size rounded to the nearest 1 or 2 decimal places, as seen using the built-in directory page? i tried `intop` but it just returns `0`. i don't understand the `Math::Script` plug-in, if it can be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps more of a math question than a NSIS question but here is simple solution:

```
!include logiclib.nsh
Section
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(t"$windir", *l.r0, *l, *l)'
    StrCpy $1 00
size:
    StrCpy $1 $1 2 ; A lazy way to "round"
    ${If} $0 U> 1024
        System::Int64op $0 % 1024
        Pop $1
        System::Int64op $0 / 1024
        Pop $0
        Goto size
    ${EndIf}
    DetailPrint $0.$1
SectionEnd
```